# LOGIN token not working in DotNetNuke

Tags: authentication, dotnetnuke-5

I've added the login token to my site so that I have a link to log into DNN in my footer. Once the skin has been parsed, the Login link appears and it sends me to the login page where I can log in which it does successfully.

The link then changes to *Logout* as it is meant to but when I click to logout, it doesn't do what it is meant to but instead take me to a version of my home page with no content.

The only thing different in this installation is that I have I have created a new login which is a parent of Admin in DNN (www.mysite.com/admin/login.aspx)

The only other thing that is different is that we're using DNN 5.6.2.

Cheers,
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to setting a different login page and then moving that login page into the Admin folder in DNN